# Are neither closed nor open set considered Borel?

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show that inverse image of Borel sets are Borel. This is easy if we consider a function $f$ that is continuous, because inverse image of open is open, closed is closed and we know those are definitely Borel.

However a generic $f$ could map some open or closed set to neither open nor closed. Are these also Borel sets? I am not sure from the definition.

Comment: What sort of function is $f$? Borel measurable? Or completely arbitrary?

Comment: For example $[0,1] \cup (4,5)$ is Borel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to believe that the preimage of a Borel set through any function is Borel (or that it has any property you want). Take $X$ to be as ugly as you please; say, not in the projective hierarchy and not Lebesgue measurable. Then simply let $f$ be the characteristic function of $X$.

If you wonder whether the image of a Borel set under a continuous mapping is Borel, this is also not the case.

Answer (score 0):

A Borel set is one that can be constructed from open sets through countable unions, countable intersections, and taking complements.